# In Jenkins pipeline how can I get the return from method to use in next stage?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

```
node() {
    stage("health check function"){
        def (healthcheck) = withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'HTTP_TOKEN', variable: 'HTTP_TOKEN')]){
                            def health_check = sh returnStdout:true, script:"""
                            #some of the script content will go here before calling the curl
                            health_check_code=\$(curl http://$URL)
                            """
                            return "${health_check_code}"
        }
    }
    stage("funcreturn"){
        def status = healthcheck()
    }
}
```

I want to get the status code from health check function stage using the `healthcheck` method so I can call this method in further stage of pipeline to get the current status code . But in **Jenkins** I am getting following error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1`.
Is it possible to get the value from method here ?

Comment: Why can't you set a variable accessible to both stages and update the value of that variable with you health_check_code?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of the code is that stages have their own scope (because `{ ... }` is a closure). That's why healthcheck can't be found in the later stage because it is basically a local variable in a function.

One way to work around this is to make it a global variable by omitting the `def` in the declaration:

```
withCredentials(){
    
    // some commands

    healthcheck = healthcheck_code // no def used to declare variable
                                   // this is a global variable
}
```

The other solution would be to (which is an lesser known fact) return from the first stage.

If you return a value from a stage, it can be assigned to a variable (at least in scripted pipelines, I don't know about declarative). If there is no explicit return the last expression will be returned. It should be possible to return from the `withCredentials` step as well (haven't tried it for myself yet)

```
def healthcheck = stage("health check function"){
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'HTTP_TOKEN', variable: 'HTTP_TOKEN')]){
                        def health_check = sh returnStdout:true, script:"""
                        #some of the script content will go here before calling the curl
                        health_check_code=\$(curl http://$URL)
                        """
                        return "${health_check_code}"
    }
}

// use healthcheck here
```

I am not sure how your healthcheck variable should be callable. Is that a groovy feature I am not aware of? My guess is that if (for whatever reason) you want to make it a function returning the value instead of the value itself, you need to enclose it in `{}` making it a anonymous function.

I cannot figure out, why you are getting the `string out of range` error, but I am pretty sure it happens outside of your code snippet.